# How to update panel width immediately

Tags: interface, add-on, panel

I am creating a popover panel and user is able to change "bl_ui_units_x" value from the Addon Preferences window. Everything works as intended, however if user changes panel width with a new one, panel is not getting updated immediately. If user changed panel width from 10 to 16, when popover panel is clicked, it is still 10. But if user closes and opens the popover panel again, then it becomes 16. My question is, how do I make sure panel width is instantly updated in the first time user opens the panel.

I thought this would work but it didn't:

```
def panel_width_update(self, context):
    bpy.context.area.tag_redraw()
```

Here is the AddonPreferences class:

```
class ADDON_PREFERENCES(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
bl_idname = __name__

addon_int_property: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="ADDON_PANEL_WIDTH", default=10, min=8, max=32, update=panel_width_update)

    row=layout.row(align=False)
    row.label(text="Panel Width:")
    row.prop(self, 'addon_int_property', text='', slider=False)
```

Panel

```
class ADDON_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
bl_idname = "ADDON_PT_PANEL"
bl_label = "ADDON"
bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
bl_region_type = 'HEADER'

def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene

    addon_prefs = context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
    self.bl_ui_units_x = addon_prefs.addon_int_property
```

Also, register and unregister functions:

```
def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.addon_int_property = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="ADDON_PANEL_WIDTH", default=10, min=8, max=32, update=panel_width_update)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.addon_int_property

    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
```

I believe my problem is with repeating this part in ADDON_PREFERENCES also in register.

```
addon_int_property: bpy.props.IntProperty(name="ADDON_PANEL_WIDTH", default=10, min=8, max=32, update=panel_width_update)
```